# How to suppress log messages for openApiGenerate task in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

Recently I tried to use OpenAPI tools for generating API from spec (yaml file with endpoints desciption). All configuration is pretty common with added mappings for schema and where it is placed in src directory.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.7.17"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "6.6.0"
}

group = 'com.example.file.service'
version = 'undefined'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0"
    implementation "org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6"
    implementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.20.45")
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:s3"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

openApiValidate {
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/server-api.yml"
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/server-api.yml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
    apiPackage = "com.example.file.service.controller"
    modelPackage = "com.example.file.service.model"
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary  : "java8",
            interfaceOnly: "true",
            useTags      : "true"
    ]
    importMappings = [
            "FileMetaDTO": "com.example.file.service.dto.FileMetaDTO",
            "ErrorDTO": "com.example.file.service.dto.ErrorDTO",
    ]
}

tasks.openApiGenerate.dependsOn tasks.processResources
compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "$buildDir/generated/src/main/java"
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "$buildDir/generated/src/main/resources"
```

Here is the example of openAPI yaml file with declared endpoint:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Cloud Storage File Service
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  # UploadFileController
  /cs-api/files/data:
    post:
      tags:
        - upload-file-controller
      summary: Upload file
      operationId: uploadFile
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              required: [ "file" ]
              properties:
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
        required: true
        description: File for saving
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: FileMetaDTO
```

Currently everything works fine, but I find it annoying when during openApiGenerate task in logs I see messages like '#/components/schemas/{pojo object} is not defined' and after that message with donation link.
Here is example of message I get every time I build project:

```
> Task :processResources

> Task :openApiGenerate
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
#/components/schemas/FileMetaDTO is not defined
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project ?                 #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
Successfully generated code to C:\Users\rifleman99\Develop-projects\file-service\build/generated

> Task :compileJava
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
```

Viewed different resources bu didn't find any relevant to my problem.
Is there any possible way to disable this type of messages for this task during build execution.